# Can't find where multiple cascade paths or cycles are in SQL Code?

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting the following error

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 99
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_linkUserGroup_tblStudent' on table >'linkUserGroup' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE ?>NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 99
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I cannot understand how a cycle or multiple cascade paths are possible? I also cannot understand how a FK constraints to the TeacherID are not causing the same problem? My understanding is that should the parent StudentID be deleted then by specifying that On Delete No Action in the child table should ensure that the record is not deleted from the child table. I don't understand how their is any other path or possible cycle? Please help

```
CREATE TABLE tblUserAccount (
uaUserAccountID INT  IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblUserAccount PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
uaUserAccountTitle NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
uaUserAccountFirstName NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
uaUserAccountSurname  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
uaUserAccountUserName NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
uaUserAccountPassword  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
uaDateTimeModified DATETIME 
    CONSTRAINT DF_tblUserAccount_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
);

CREATE TABLE tblRole (
rRoleID INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblRole PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
rRole NVARCHAR (50),
rRoleDescription NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
rDateTimeModified DATETIME 
    CONSTRAINT DF_tblRole_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
);

CREATE TABLE linkUserAccountRole (
uarUserAccountID INT,
uarRoleID   INT,
uarDateTimeModified DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_linkUserAccountRole_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_linkUserAcccountRole 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (uarUserAccountID , uarRoleID)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserAcccountRole_tblRole 
        FOREIGN KEY (uarRoleID) 
        REFERENCES tblRole (rRoleID) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserAcccountRole_tblUserAccount 
        FOREIGN KEY (uarUserAccountID) 
        REFERENCES tblUserAccount (uaUserAccountID) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE tblTeacher (
tTeacherID  INT CONSTRAINT PK_tblTeacher PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
tUserAccountID INT,
tDateTimeModified DATETIME 
    CONSTRAINT DF_tblTeacher_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblTeacher_tblUserAccount 
        FOREIGN KEY (tUserAccountID) 
        REFERENCES tblUserAccount(uaUserAccountID)  
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE tblStudent (
sStudentID  INT CONSTRAINT PK_tblStudent PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
sUserAccountID INT,
sDateTimeModified DATETIME 
    CONSTRAINT DF_tblStudent_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblStudent_tblUserAccount 
        FOREIGN KEY (sUserAccountID) 
        REFERENCES tblUserAccount(uaUserAccountID)  
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE

);

CREATE TABLE tblKeyStage (
ksKeyStageGroupID INT IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblKeyStage PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
ksKeyStageTitle NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ksKeyStageDescription  NVARCHAR(50),
ksDateTimeModified DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_tblKeyStage_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME() 
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_tblKeyStage_KeyStageTitle UNIQUE (ksKeyStageTitle)
);

CREATE TABLE tblYearGroup (
ygYearGroupID INT IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblYearGroup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
ygYearGroupTitle NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ygYearGroupDescription NVARCHAR(50),
ygDateTimeModified DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_tblYearGroup_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_tblYearGroup_YearGroupTitle UNIQUE (ygYearGroupTitle)
);

CREATE TABLE tblClassGroup (
cgClassGroupID INT IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblClassGroup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
cgClassGroupTitle NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
cgClassGroupDescription    NVARCHAR (50),
cgDateTimeModified  DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_tblClassGroup_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_tblClassGroup_ClassGroupTitle UNIQUE (cgClassGroupTitle)
);

CREATE TABLE tblLearningGroup (
lgLearningGroupID INT IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblLearningGroup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
lgLearningGroupTitle NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
lgLearningGroupDescription NVARCHAR (50),
lgDateTimeModified DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_tblLearningGroup_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_tblLearningGroup_LearningGroupTitle UNIQUE (lgLearningGroupTitle)
);

CREATE TABLE tblLearningGroup (
lgLearningGroupID INT IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_tblLearningGroup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
lgLearningGroupTitle NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
lgLearningGroupDescription NVARCHAR (50),
lgDateTimeModified DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_tblLearningGroup_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_tblLearningGroup_LearningGroupTitle UNIQUE (lgLearningGroupTitle)
);

CREATE TABLE linkUserGroup (
ugTeacherID INT,
ugStudentID INT,
ugKeyStageGroupID INT,
ugYearGroupID INT,
ugClassGroupID INT,
ugLearningGroupID INT,
ugDateTimeModified DATETIME 
     CONSTRAINT DF_linkUserGroup_DateTimeModified DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_linkUserGroup 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ugTeacherID, ugStudentID, ugClassGroupID, ugLearningGroupID)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserGroup_tblTeacher 
        FOREIGN KEY (ugTeacherID) 
        REFERENCES tblTeacher (tTeacherID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserGroup_tblStudent 
        FOREIGN KEY (ugStudentID) 
        REFERENCES tblStudent (sStudentID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserGroup_tblKeyStage 
        FOREIGN KEY (ugKeyStageGroupID) 
        REFERENCES tblKeyStage (ksKeyStageGroupID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserGroup_tblYearGroup 
        FOREIGN KEY (ugYearGroupID) 
        REFERENCES tblYearGroup (ygYearGroupID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserGroup_tblClassGroup
        FOREIGN KEY (ugClassGroupID) 
        REFERENCES tblClassGroup (cgClassGroupID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_linkUserGroup_tblLearningGroup 
        FOREIGN KEY (ugLearningGroupID) 
        REFERENCES tblLearningGroup (lgLearningGroupID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_linkUserGroup_PK_YearGroupID 
        UNIQUE (ugTeacherID, ugStudentID, ugClassGroupID, ugLearningGroupID, ugYearGroupID) 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple cascade paths exist between `tblUserAccount` and `linkUserGroup`:

```
tblUserAccount -> tblTeacher -> linkUserGroup
tblUserAccount -> tblStudent -> linkUserGroup
```

[image]

It is not the FK constraint itself which is not allowed, but the action: `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

You can either specify `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for `FK_linkUserGroup_tblTeacher`, or `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for `FK_linkUserGroup_tblStudent`, but not for both.

Your `ON DELETE` is already marked as `NO ACTION`, so it is fine. It is `ON UPDATE` which you should decide what to do.

There are 2 options:

1) Forbid updating the key which participates in a FK constraint.

To do that specify `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, or just remove the `ON UPDATE` clause altogether, because this is the default behaviour of a foreign key constraint.

Considering that updating a primary key is usually not a good idea (whether it is referenced by a foreign key or not), I would recommend this option.

2) If automatic propagation of changed `sStudentID` and `tTeacherID` to `linkUserGroup` is really what you want, then you can use triggers.